# How can I just clear an item with a name, not all items of the same type?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

To start off, I just want to say this is probably easy but I am tired and just getting the hang of this. But anyway, I am trying to make a command block that when activated will clear your inventory of any iron boots with the custom name JumpBoost. This works, but it also clears your inventory of any other iron boots that aren't named. The command I am using is:

```
clear @a iron_boots 0 1 {display:{Name:"JumpBoost"}}
```

I don't really use the /clear command, so I am lost.
(I am in 1.7.10 and cannot get 1.8 right now)

Comment: In 1.7.10, that is not possible. (You can't clear items based on their NBT tags)

Comment: @aytimothy Thanks! I knew you could do it in 1.8 versions, but I didn't know about 1.7.

Comment: When you are able to upgrade, you're also going to want to set the `data` (damage) value to -1 so as to ignore it.  Otherwise, it'll only match boots with a damage value of 0, which might not be all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't

Long answer: 1.7 does not support NBT filtering for the clear command.